# how can i partition the HDD in ubuntu 12.10 64bit ? - only have ubuntu as OS on notebook

Tags: 12.10, partitioning, hard-drive

> i got a new notebook dell n4050 with os ubuntu 10.10 and i upgrade it
>   to 12.10 64bit , I have only ubuntu 12.10 64bit on my notebook , HDD
>   space is 320 GB , when i log into os , i found (desktop , computer and
>   filesystem )folders ,

i want to partition the HDD means don't want to have 1 partiton with 320 gb as i have no , but want to add a new partitons to allocate .

> such as in windwos you have partitions "C" , "D" and "E" and others ,
>   so i want to allocate 1 partition to filesystem and 2 partitons to my
>   files like a movies, education , music and others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a **live CD/DVD or USB** to do that.

For example, you can use Ubuntu **Startup Disk Creator** to create an **Ubuntu live USB**.

Then **boot your computer from this USB** (by changing BIOS settings, boot priority or by entering boot menu command -- which vary between computers: Delete, Esc, F2, F9, F10 or F2).

When you are in **Ubuntu Live session**, you can start **GParted Partition Editor** and re-partition your hard disk.

Comment: you mean i use live cd only to partiton hdd then back to my install OS ?? i don't want ot use ubuntu from live cd , i want it to be the only os in my notebook

Comment: Of course, you can keep Ubuntu as the only OS in your notebook. Why you need live CD/DVD/USB is you won't be able to do any partitioning on that disk while you're using it. In live session, you'll need to **shrink** your Ubuntu partition (reduce its size) without affecting your OS, and **create free space between Ubuntu and Linux-Swap partitions** so that you can make another partition to store your documents, music, pictures, videos, etc. For example, you can allocate 25GB for Ubuntu, 4GB for Swap (at the very end), and create one or two partitions in between.

Comment: i made that , but i can't use those new two partitions ,i can't make a new folders or paste in thing in it , there is only folder called" lost+found" in  ,  and when i get properties and tab permission , i find a message that i'm not the owner so i can't change it ???

Comment: My solution for this was: 1) Open the file fstab as root with this terminal command: `sudo gedit /etc/fstab` 2) Add two lines for your ntfs partitions at the end of the list there like this: `UUID=7E8632EA140568B5  /media/Documents  ntfs  defaults,uid=1000,gid=46,utf8,dmask=000,fmask=111  0  0`  Of course you should use your partition uuid number instead of **7E8632EA140568B5** and your partition's label instead of **Documents** in this example. Saving this file and rebooting should solve the permissions problem.

Comment: Note: **UUID** and **Label** of a partition can be seen via **GParted** context menu **Information**.

Comment: sadi , i solved it , the problem was when i add new partitions i make it as ex2 , but after your notes , i comeback to live cd and changed tybe to NTFS , then boot from hdd and it's now working normally :) , thanks sadi for your care